# Xaudio2 pop sound when changing buffer or looping

Tags: c++, audio, xaudio2

I have a simple program that plays a sine wave.
At the end of the buffer I get a pop sound.
If I try to loop I get the pop sound between each loop.
If I alternate between buffers I get the pop sound.

```
struct win32_audio_buffer
{
    XAUDIO2_BUFFER XAudioBuffer = {};
    int16 *Memory;
};

struct win32_audio_setteings
{
    int32 SampleRate = 44100;
    int32 ToneHz = 200;
    int32 Channels = 2;
    int32 LoopTime = 10;
    int32 TotalSamples = SampleRate * LoopTime;
};

win32_audio_setteings AudioSetteings;
win32_audio_buffer MainAudioBuffer;
win32_audio_buffer SecondaryAudioBuffer;
IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice;

internal void Win32InitXaudio2()
{
    WAVEFORMATEX WaveFormat = {};
    WaveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    WaveFormat.nChannels = AudioSetteings.Channels;
    WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = AudioSetteings.SampleRate;
    WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    WaveFormat.nBlockAlign = (WaveFormat.nChannels * WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample) / 8;
    WaveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec * WaveFormat.nBlockAlign;
    WaveFormat.cbSize = 0;
    
    IXAudio2* pXAudio2;
    IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasterVoice;
    
    XAudio2Create(&pXAudio2);
    pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice(&pMasterVoice);
    
    pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice(&pSourceVoice, &WaveFormat);
}
//DOC: AudioBytes - Size of the audio data
//DOC: pAudioData - The buffer start loaction (Needs to be type cast into BYTE pointer)
internal void Win32CreateAudioBuffer(win32_audio_buffer *AudioBuffer)
{
    int32 Size = (int16)sizeof(int16) * AudioSetteings.Channels * AudioSetteings.SampleRate * AudioSetteings.LoopTime;
    
    AudioBuffer->Memory = (int16 *)VirtualAlloc(0, Size, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    
    AudioBuffer->XAudioBuffer.AudioBytes = Size;   
    AudioBuffer->XAudioBuffer.pAudioData = (BYTE *) AudioBuffer->Memory;  
    //AudioBuffer->XAudioBuffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;
    AudioBuffer->XAudioBuffer.PlayBegin = 0;
    AudioBuffer->XAudioBuffer.PlayLength = AudioSetteings.TotalSamples;
    //AudioBuffer->XAudioBuffer.LoopCount = 10;
    
}

internal void Win32Playback(win32_audio_buffer *AudioBuffer)
{
    for (int32 Index = 0, Sample = 0; Sample < AudioSetteings.TotalSamples; Sample++)
    {
        real32 Sine = sinf(Sample * 2.0f * Pi32 / AudioSetteings.ToneHz);
        int16 value = (int16)(4000 * Sine);
        AudioBuffer->Memory[Index++] = value;
        AudioBuffer->Memory[Index++] = value;
    }
    pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&AudioBuffer->XAudioBuffer);
}

Win32InitXaudio2();
Win32CreateAudioBuffer(&MainAudioBuffer);
//Win32CreateAudioBuffer(&SecondaryAudioBuffer);
Win32Playback(&MainAudioBuffer);
//Win32Playback(&SecondaryAudioBuffer);
pSourceVoice->Start(0);
```

I have posted the relevant code here and it just play one sine buffer.
I tried altrantaing buffers and to start and end on a zero-crossing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Maybe it will help someone.

The problem is in allocating more memory for audio  than needed.

So I tried something like this and found the problem (this is not solution I just show how I found problem! Probably, if it will not help in your case, then the problem somewhere else)

```
// XAUDIO2_BUFFER m_xaudio2Buffer...
m_xaudio2Buffer.pAudioData = source->m_data;
m_xaudio2Buffer.AudioBytes = source->m_dataSize - 100; // -100 and `pop` sound is gone
m_xaudio2Buffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;
```